# Unable to import table with Camel Case naming convention

Tags: postgresql

i am working with PostgreSQL database. I have my all tables following camel case naming convention for columns. How to use same structure with PostgreSQL>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All identifiers (including column names) that are not double-quoted are folded to lower case in PostgreSQL.

Column names that were created with double-quotes and thereby retained upper-case letters (and/or other syntax violations) have to be double-quoted for the rest of their life.

So, in PostgreSQL column names are case-sensitive depending on the way they are created.

I recommend you to create column names in lower case so that you can query them the way you prefer.

Comment: So for camel case i need to put column name in double quotes?

Comment: Yes, like: SELECT * FROM user WHERE "firstName" ILIKE 'adynh'; However I recommend using lower-case names exclusively so double-quoting is not needed.